# How can I cancel or stop thread when back button is pressed?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have been working with thread since last few days.I want to stop my thread when I press back button in navigation bar.But I couldn't find the solution to stop this background thread.If anybody know then please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have done like this to run a function in background 
i.e

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(myFunction) withObject:nil];
```

then to cancel it you can use this code

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(myFunction) object:nil];
```

Comment: Hi Ajeet,Thanks for help.But it didn't stop my background process.

Comment: but in my case i am using the same code and it stops my background process.

Comment: just change the function name in my code i.e myFunction to your function name i.e loadimagefromurl.  by the way you should use camel case while giving name to function loadImageFromUrl.

Comment: Ya just did it but still  not stop to run background..i just changed only function name...by the way thanks for you support.

Comment: I don't think this works anymore. If you look at the class definition for @(cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget), it only applies to @(performSelector:withObject:afterDelay).

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `NSOperation` and poll the `isCancelled` property to stop your thread from running.